# How to design a type representing a string neither null nor white space

Tags: c#, .net, string, struct, c#-7.0

Many times we pass strings in the constructor of business entities and we want to be sure that those strings actually carry a value with them. In such a scenario we perform a validation of the constructor parameters and we throw an `ArgumentException` each time the passed in string is null or white space.

This is an example of what I mean:

```
public class Person 
{
   public string Name { get; }

   public Person(string name)
   {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("A person name cannot be null or white space", nameof(name));
      }

      this.Name = name;
   }
}
```

Tired of repeting myself I decided to design an auto safe type representing a string neither null nor white space. This way I can directly use instances of that type in my business code and avoid any validation, because each instance of the type is auto safe (in other words the validation code is now in one place, the code for the type itself).

This is the `NonEmptyString` struct (original code is [here](https://github.com/deltatre-webplu/deltatre.utils/blob/master/src/Deltatre.Utils/Types/NonEmptyString.cs)):

```
using System;

namespace Deltatre.Utils.Types
{
  /// <summary>
  /// This type wraps a string which is guaranteed to be neither null nor white space
  /// </summary>
  public struct NonEmptyString
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Implicit conversion from <see cref="NonEmptyString"/> to <see cref="string"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nonEmptyString">The instance of <see cref="NonEmptyString"/> to be converted</param>
    public static implicit operator string(NonEmptyString nonEmptyString)
    {
      return nonEmptyString.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Explicit conversion from <see cref="string"/> to <see cref="NonEmptyString"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The instance of <see cref="string"/> to be converted</param>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidCastException">Throws <see cref="InvalidCastException"/> when <paramref name="value"/> is null or white space</exception>
    public static explicit operator NonEmptyString(string value)
    {
      try
      {
        return new NonEmptyString(value);
      }
      catch (ArgumentException ex)
      {
        throw new InvalidCastException($"Unable to convert the provided string to {typeof(NonEmptyString).Name}", ex);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates new instance of <see cref="NonEmptyString"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The string to be wrapped</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Throws <see cref="ArgumentException"/> when parameter <paramref name="value"/> is null or white space</exception>
    public NonEmptyString(string value)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        throw new ArgumentException($"Parameter {nameof(value)} cannot be null or white space", nameof(value));

      this.Value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the wrapped string
    /// </summary>
    public string Value { get; }

    /// <summary>Indicates whether this instance and a specified object are equal.</summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare with the current instance. </param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <see langword="true" /> if <paramref name="obj" /> and this instance are the same type and represent the same value; otherwise, <see langword="false" />. </returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      if (!(obj is NonEmptyString))
      {
        return false;
      }

      var other = (NonEmptyString)obj;
      return this.Value == other.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>Returns the hash code for this instance.</summary>
    /// <returns>A 32-bit signed integer that is the hash code for this instance.</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      unchecked
      {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = (hash * 23) + (this.Value == null ? 0 : this.Value.GetHashCode());
        return hash;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares two instances of <see cref="NonEmptyString"/> for equality
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">An instance of <see cref="NonEmptyString"/></param>
    /// <param name="right">An instance of <see cref="NonEmptyString"/></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool operator ==(NonEmptyString left, NonEmptyString right)
    {
      return left.Equals(right);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares two instances of <see cref="NonEmptyString"/> for inequality
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">An instance of <see cref="NonEmptyString"/></param>
    /// <param name="right">An instance of <see cref="NonEmptyString"/></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool operator !=(NonEmptyString left, NonEmptyString right)
    {
      return !(left == right);
    }
  }
}
```

Using my new type I can change the previous code this way:

```
public class Person 
{
  public NonEmptyString Name { get; }

  public Person(NonEmptyString name)
  {          
    this.Name = name;
  }
}
```

The only issue with this design is represented by the **default constructor** which is always available because my type is a `struct`.

If anyone using my code writes `var myString = new NonEmptyString();` he gets an instance of the type which encapsulates a `null` reference: this is something I would like to avoid because doing so the entire purpose of my auto safe type is invalidated. In other words I don't want to rely on the programmer not calling the default constructor, I would like to make it impossible to misuse this type.

I came up with a couple of ideas:

- provide a default value for the read only property `Value`, something such as "N.A.". This way even when the default constructor is called the instance obtained encapsulates a non null and non white space value.
- adding a flag indicating whether the type has been initialized, having a default value of `false`. This state is read only and it is changed to `true` only in the constructor overload receiving a string parameter. This way a guard can be added to any member of the type, so that an `InvalidOperationException` can be raised each time a programmer tries to use a non initialized instance of the type (that is, an instance of the type obtained by calling the default constructor).

Do you have any suggestion ? What approach do you prefer ?

Comment: ooooorrr make it a class?

Comment: @Dave it is a struct because a struct is always guarantee to have a value, it cannot be a null reference. Let's suppose to make it a class. Doing so each time I use an instance of `NonEmptyString` I have to check whether it is a null reference. I would like to avoid so, in other words I would like to be sure that given an instance of `NonEmptyString` I have an actual value

Comment: mmm yeah that's a valid point. Can you use c# 8's non-nullable reference types? or you could throw an exception in the parameterless ctor? I dont like that, but I'm just spitballing, as they say

Comment: @Dave unfortunately with C# 7 you cannot edit the default constructor of a struct. So the idea of adding a guard to it is not feasible. C# 8 with the idea of non nullable reference type could be helful. At the moment I can only evaluate to use it in new projects, because the change in the reference type semantic is a massive breaking change (there are plenty of code bases written under the assumption that a reference type can be null, based on what I know the default of C# 8 is assuming that a reference type cannot be null, you can be explicit if you want it to be nullable)

Comment: my opinion is this... unless your default value is valid/useful in someway, how is 'N/A' or 'empty string' any better than an actual empty string? A default value is only useful if its valid, otherwise its literally pointless

Comment: So as much as I dont like that it is run time validation as apposed to compile time, I think options 2 is better

Comment: @Dave I agree with you. The idea of providing a meaningless default value just to avoid a null reference is a trick. Probably throwing at runtime it's better. That's the same approach Microsoft has used with Nullable<T>. in that case you are free to access the Value of an instance even when the value itself is missing, but in that case you get an InvalidOperationException at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using auto property, you can use backing field `_value` and implement getter for `Value` property instead. like

```cs
public string Value => _value ?? "";
```

Then make every function works when `_value` is null;

Comment: the empty string is one of the values this type is meant to avoid. It's fine to provide a default value for uninitialized instances, but that value can't be null, string.empty or a sequence of spaces. Apart from this, you are basically suggesting of providing a default value for instances obtained via the default constructor, which is the first of my two proposals.

Comment: You can use `_value ?? "N/A"` if you want it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question well but I assume from

> The idea of providing a meaningless default value just to avoid a null
>   reference is a trick. Probably throwing at runtime it's better. That's
>   the same approach Microsoft has used with Nullable. in that case
>   you are free to access the Value of an instance even when the value
>   itself is missing

```
public class Person 
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                value = "NA";
            }
            _name = value;
        }
    }

   public Person(string name)
   {
      this.Name = name;
   }
}
```

This probably might help you. The code is untested, It is just to give you a glimpse of what you might be looking for.

Comment: The whole point of my question is not how to actually implement a fallback value, instead I'm looking for suggestions about the whole design of my type. I mean suggestions in order to get a type easy to use, well written and useful for the purpose of avoiding code repetition. In the comment you quoted above I was just saying that I don't like too much the idea of providing a fallback value, becase a value such as "N.A." doesn't have a real meaning, it's just a way to always have a non null fallback for the Value property.